# Keep windows GUI while switching windows user or closing remote connection

Tags: windows, autohotkey, remote-desktop

I need to run a GUI script (AutoHotKey, which makes mouse clicks and press keys) on:

1. A different windows user (i.e. I run the script, then switch user
   while keeping the session active)
2. A remote Amazon windows server (using remote desktop) where I also
   run the script then close the Remote Desktop while keeping the
   instance running

Unfortunately, in both cases, the script doesn't run as it seems that Windows enters a "GUI-less" mode where all GUI components are not active anymore.

Is there any solution to this?

Any hint would be greatly appreciated as I've now lost days trying to solve this!

Many thanks, Thomas

Comment: From a security standpoint it would be a bad idea to allow a process with first user's privileges to run on second user's desktop. Second user must start its own process. The process can start automatically if it is registered to start so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible due to the way Remote Desktop is implemented. When you close the RD connection, the GUI is no longer drawn.  Therefore, AutoHotkey is unable to perform mouse clicks and key presses.

A possible workaround would be to make some registry tweaks (if possible on your server) which allow GUI interaction while minimized.

1. Locate `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client`
2. Create `RemoteDesktop SuppressWhenMinimized` as DWORD with a value of 2

[Registry Tweak Source](http://blog.smartbear.com/software-quality/testcomplete-tip-running-tests-in-minimized-remote-desktop-windows/)